# How to limit the size of Bootsrap panels?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I want to create dashboard using bootstrap panels.

Now I want the panels to be of equal size, if the data is more then i want to automatically set the overflow to scroll. I want to have three equal sized pannels in each row in which i will fetch data from database

I did this but didn't work:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h2 class="panel-title">Last 10 Inserted Users</h2>
            </div>
             <div class="panel-body" style="overflow:hidden;">        


             My PHP code to fetch data which maybe small or large

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: add also `max-height:__px`

Comment: So the problem is, you are not getting equal height?

Comment: @PhpDeveloper this didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below mentioned css will fix the height of the div where you have content:

```
.panel-body {
  height:300px;//change it to your desired height
  overflow-y: scroll;//will apply scroll on the vertical axis when your content goes beyond 300px
}
```

Comment: I want to have overflow to scroll i there more data

Comment: set overflow-y as scroll. hope that solved your problem. if not then please comment.

Answer (score 0):

> For Panel Size limitation You can code like this..

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
<div class="panel-body" style="min-height: 10; max-height: 10;">Body</div>
</div>
```